# List all users that have permission for a given table in Dynamics ax 2009

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have some custom table, that was implemented by some company years ago in our environment.

I need to list users and their permissions to this table. 
I found about ACCESSRIGHTSLIST table that has everything I want, like groups and therefore associated  users.

Problem is that this list is incomplete, users are able to modify/view this table outside of the groups I found by ACCESSRIGHTSLIST.

I know that dicttable.rights() would do nicely, but I cannot specify user here, it only validates for the user that is executing the code.

What I basicaly need is dicttable.rights(someUserID), but since I cannot see what mechanism is dicttable using, I'm stuck.

I work in AX 2009.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, create a `static server` method and use the `runas` command to call it, where you `runas` the different users you want.

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-session-run-time-functions
- https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/66819

Or search the system for sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to AX 2009 now but as far as I remember you should be able to use system class `SecurityKeySet`. Check if the following works:

```
SecurityKeySet  securityKeySet; 
AccessType      accessType;
UserId          userId      = curUserId();
TableId         tableId     = tableNum(CustTable);
;

securityKeySet = new SecurityKeySet(); 
securityKeySet.loadUserRights(userId);

accessType = securityKeySet.tableAccess(tableId);

info(strFmt('%1', accessType));
```

Comment: A better answer here. I answered your question, this answers your need.